Not understading how to get link for a private app
I already published my app which I released as Private Mode by providing Organization Id.  And the Application is ready for Distribution but there is no link for sharing in "Apps Connect" or "Apple Business Manager". And there is another issue in "Pricing and Availability" which shows that in "App Availability": "1 can not sell" but before releasing the app i am sure that i choose "India" for release and my app is totally free, there is no monetization as well.And also I already contact to the apple team via mail but from them there is no response. How to procced further to get the link of the private app?



I have tried to conact with apple developer supper but there is no result. I want to know how to share the application with my user.

Since you have distributed your app as a private app, it is only available in Apple Business Manager for the organisation that you have added.  It is visible in the "Custom apps" section of ABM

@Paulw11 Yes, i looked for that one but i didn't understand how to share the app to the user

Once you have purchased the app in ABM you can either distribute it via an MDM (this is the recommended method) or you can get redemption codes and provide a code to each user.

@Paulw11 its my 1st custom application in Ios so i can't understand how to do things properly. Is there any way to get some help from you.
